# Rails, Rack:SSL don't work on thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, https, rack, thin

I want to have https for entire application.

I decided to use this gem:

https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer

However after  adding at end

```
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer'
```

in Gemfile and

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer
```

in `application.rb` at end I get error:

```
/path_to_app/www/.ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send': undefined method `Rack' for #<App1::Application:0xf6dcb314> (NoMethodError)
    from /path_to_app/www/.ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /path_to_app/www/stolikarnia/config/application.rb:57
    from /path_to_app/www/.ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:21:in `require'
    from /path_to_app/www/.ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:21
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

As you see from logs i use Rails 3.0.9. I can't upgrade to RoR 3.1.0 because of dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Gemfile` change the requirement to

```
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer', :require => 'rack/ssl-enforcer'
```

Then, in your `application.rb` pass the class name as `String` to take advantage of lazy evaluation.

```
config.middleware.use "Rack::SslEnforcer"
```

As a side note, I encourage you to check https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl. It's the middleware introduced in Rails 3.1. You can already use it in Rails 3.0 with the additional benefit you won't need to change it once you'll upgrade to Rails 3.1.

Comment: Thanks. After adding `require` and changing const to string it works. However probably certificate is no installed correctly because firefox browser don't show that cert is verified.